# Side by side violin plots for multiple iteration

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data

```
set.seed(42)
dat = data.frame(iter = rep(1:3, each = 10),
                 variable = rep(rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), 3),
                 value = rnorm(30))
```

I know I can draw violin plots for `a` and `b` with

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes (x = variable, y = value)) + geom_violin()
```

[image]

But how do I draw violin plots for each iteration of `a` and `b` so that there will be three plots for `a` next to three plots for `b`. I have done it previously using base plot but I am looking for a better solution since the number of iterations as well as number of 'a's and 'b's keeps on changing.

Comment: Have you considering adding aes(..., fill = as.factor(iter))? And later on if you don't like color you can redefine scale_fill_manual(). Does this help?

Comment: If you prefer a vertical line you could try the following: ggplot(data = dat, aes (x = as.factor(iter), y = value)) + geom_violin(position = "dodge") + facet_wrap(~variable)

Comment: or you could use `+ geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5)` for the verticl line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible ways. One would be by adding a fill command, the other using `facet_wrap` (or `facet_grid`)

With fill:
`ggplot(data = dat, aes (x = variable, y = value, fill = as.factor(iter))) + geom_violin(position = "dodge")`

[image]

Or using `facet_wrap`:
`ggplot(data = dat, aes (x = as.factor(iter), y = value)) + geom_violin(position = "dodge") + facet_wrap(~variable)`[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better way but in this kind of situation I usually create a new variable:

```
set.seed(42)
dat = data.frame(iter = rep(1:3, each = 10),
                 variable = rep(rep(letters[1:2], each = 5), 3),
                 value = rnorm(30))



dat <- dat %>% mutate(x_axis = as.factor(as.numeric(factor(variable))*100 + 10*iter))


levels(dat$x_axis)<- c("a1", "a", "a3", "b2", "b", "b3")



ggplot(data = dat, 
       aes(x = x_axis, 
            y = value, fill =variable)) + geom_violin() + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("a","b"))
```

Result is:

[image]